# Confusing calling method in Java

Tags: java

```
class Parent
{
    private void method1()
    {
        System.out.println("Parent's method1()");
    }
    public void method2()
    {
        System.out.println("Parent's method2()");
        method1();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    public void method1()
    {
        System.out.println("Child's method1()");        
    }
}
class test {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Parent p = new Child();
        p.method2();
    }
}
```

I'm confuse why  does in Parent::method2() when invoking method1() it will cal Parents method1() and not Childs method1 ? I see that this happens only when method1() is private? Can someone explain me why ?
Thanks you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens based on scoping rules; in `Parent` the best match for `method1` is the class-local private version.

If you were to define `method1` as `public` or `protected` in `Parent` and override the method in `Child`, then calling `method2` would invoke `Child`'s `method1` instead.

Comment: for his example, may as well add `friendly` to the list.

Comment: i guess he ment friend :) Thanks for explination Mark Elliot

Comment: Friendly refers to the absence of a public/protected/private designator.  Friendly methods are accessible by any class in the same package. Friends, that is what I meant. :)

Comment: friend concept is in c++ not in java. In java no-modifier or default modifier. These default modifiers are confusing to detect by reflection and hence i dont like them too much, anyway its out of context here.

Answer (score 5):

`private` methods can't be overriden, hence the `method1` you specify on `Child` isn't linked. `javac` assumes you must mean the `method1` on the parent. Changing it to `protected` will work.

Comment: JLS reference: [8.4.8.1 Overriding (by Instance Methods)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#227927)